# Can state space matrix initial conditions be set by signals in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, state-space

I want to feed the initial conditions in state space matrix block in simulink by using signals "from-go to signal blocks". I m trying it with signal blocks but some errors pop up at the end and it says that the signal variables used as initial conditions are all undefined variable. In other words there exists "Undefined function or variable".

Any help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are using the [State-Space](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/statespace.html) block. The "initial conditions" parameter for the block is just that, a parameter:

[image]

You need to understand the difference between a parameter and a signal: a parameter is something that is constant throughout the simulation (e.g. a variable in the MATLAB workspace), whereas a signal is something whose value is updated at each time step. You cannot use a "signal" to parameterise a block, it's not possible, you can only use a parameter. Hope that clears things up.

If I misunderstood your question, please provide more details, including which block(s) you are using and if possible a screenshot of the model and the relevant block parameters.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer. I think you are right that initial conditions section in state space matrix is just a parameter and we cant update in simulink while it is running.